# Nomenclature: Collection of sets in which each set has some element unique to it

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

A collection $\mathcal{X}$ of sets may have the property that each member of the collection has some element unique to it, more precisely, that for each element $A$ of $\mathcal{X}$, for some object $x$, for every element $X$ of $\mathcal{X}$, $x \in X$ if and only if $X = A$ (equivalently, there is no element $A$ of $\mathcal{X}$ such that $A \subset \bigcup (\mathcal{X} - \{A\})$).  Is there some recognized name for this property?

One reason that there might be is that it is a necessary and sufficient condition for the mapping $u \colon \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X}) \to \mathcal{P}(\bigcup \mathcal{X})$, $u \colon A \mapsto \bigcup A$ to be an injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such collections are known as [minimal covers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalCover.html).